# CentOS VPS show time same as in India though situated in US

Tags: mongodb, meteor, momentjs, centos7, vps

If right now VPS situated in US shows time "Mon Sep 25 20:23:56 UTC 2017",
my local machine in India show time "Mon Sep 25 20:25:36 UTC+5:30 2017"(appx 2 minutes early on VPS).

My problem is When I save `date` to mongodb remote it save as `"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-25T20:23:56.461Z")` and when I see website on my local machine the time shows `Tue Sep 26 01:33 UTC 2017`. I seriously don't understand what is wrong??

why UTC+5:30 on my local machine? and how come the VPS server time is same as Indian Standard time?

Comment: How exactly do you get time on your local machine and on VPS?

Comment: My machine is set to UTC+5:30 TIMEZONE. on VPS it is what it is? Exactly what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Check the system time with `date` command.
All the servers should sync time with NTP server to avoid this kind of issues.

```
yum install ntp
chkconfig ntpd on
ntpdate pool.ntp.org  // You can use ur own NTP server 
service ntpd start
```